# Why show that "randomPack " index is undefined

Tags: php

Here is my code where i Try  fetch random actions from session:

```
        $data = array();

        $rndPack = $_SESSION['randomPack'];
        $fromSession = (isset($_SESSION['randomPack'])) ? explode(',', $rndPack) : array();

        if(isset($fromSession['expire']) AND $fromSession['expire'] < time())
        {
            $fromSession = NULL;
        }
```

Comment: Only use `$_SESSION['randomPack']` after `isset` function. You are using it before, to set a value to `$rndPack`. Also, if you use a variable only once in your code, it is better to use the full value instead, in this case, `$_SESSION['randomPack']`

Comment: `$rndPack = $_SESSION['randomPack'];`. You should check presence of `randomPack` in session array before assigning it.

Comment: Did you use `session_start()`?

Comment: so can i use,  if(array_key_exists('randomPack',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['randomPack'])) {
   $fromSession = (isset($_SESSION['randomPack'])) ? explode(',', $rndPack) : array();
}

Comment: no i don't use session_start()